# Safely accessing property of object in php

Tags: php

Is this always safe or could it cause errors in some cases?

```
if(isset($myVar) && $myVar->myProp !== 'error') {
   ...
```

Comment: It could cause an error if it doesn't exist... But ofcourse, you're checking it exists before you use it, right?

Comment: ok, tried making it more clear

Comment: To me, it's the same question to before the edit.

Comment: You could use is_object

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a case of defining properties on the fly. While it's possible (and valid) to use `property_exists()`, it would be *much* better to actually enforce the existance of the property in the class definition:

```
Class someExample {
  public $myProp = false; // now it will ALWAYS exist for any instance of someExample
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will cause an error if the property doesn't exist. Check it exists with [**`property_exists`**](https://www.php.net/property_exists)

```
$myVar = new myVar();
if( (isset($myVar) && property_exists('myVar', 'myProp')) 
     && $myVar->myProp !== 'error' ) {

}
```